# Can we inherit private members of a Base class into public members of a Derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, public, private-members

The problem is I need Base-class's Private members into Derived-class Public members but there I can find only two main types of keywords to Inherit `private` which is the default type and `public` which Inherit all things as same as they are in Base-class. But I need to inherit only Private members of the Base-class into public members of the Derived-class.
Can someone help me out with this!

Comment: I suggest to provide a real use case why you only need to inherit *private members* . Most of time composite or aggregate pattern is better than inheritance in such case. A [mre] is even better.

Comment: The short answer is: no, you cannot do what you have described. The longer answer is: there's probably a good way to solve whatever your real situation is, but it's not in terms of making private members public via inheritance.

Comment: A derived class cannot *use* private members of the base class, much less *let others use* them.

Comment: If you need to to do that , there is a flaw in the design.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you feel this need?

Answer (score 1):

You wants a class `Base` has `publicData` and `privateData`, but only `privateData` is inherited in derived class.

This is might be an XY problem.
I presume you want two classes to have "some data" in common, but achieving it by inheritance in inappropriate is this case.

Partially inheritance break the concept of inheritance, and I suggest to use composition.

Most of time composition and aggregation are the better solution.

Here's a composition example for using the same private data without inheritance.

If you really need to inherit private data, make them protected in `Base` and no public data. Or multiple inheritances which I suggest only use interface style won't bite you less in the future.

If this cannot answer your question, please update your question for detailed use case. Eg: you need to refactor something or some limitation.

```cpp
struct Data{
int val;
};

class Base{
public:
void SomeFunction();

protected:
Data m_Data;
};


class Derived: public Base{
// You will have protected m_Data here.
};

class AnotherClass{ // A class has data in common
private:
Data m_Data;
};
```